# Move menu items to a dropdown menu when they exceed the width of the menu [*for Responsiveness]

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, menu, responsive-design

I have a menu like the one below, and on some screen resolutions it exceeds the width of the menu and goes on two rows. So, I was thinking to move the items that don't fit to a dropdown menu that will be placed in the same menu.

```
<ul>
  <li>Menu Item</li>
  <li>Menu Item</li>
  <li>Menu Item</li>
  <li>Menu Item</li>
  <li>Menu Item</li>
</ul>
```

Is there a jQuery plugin to help me do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of [Media Queries](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_mediatypes.asp) in CSS for this problem.

For instance:

```
@media all and (max-width: 640px) and (min-width: 240px) {
  #fulllength_menu {
   //Hide menu that's displayed for screens bigger than 640px
    display:none;
  }
  #minimobile_menu{
    //Hide menu that's displayed for screens smaller than 640px but bigger than 240px
    display:block;
  }
}
```

[Check our this tutorial for more details](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/)

**OR**

You can go by feature detection through a nifty script called Modernizr and load custom CSS files when your website is being viewed on a mobile device.

[Check it out here](http://modernizr.com/)

Comment: thanks. I have tried with media-queries, but didn't get me what I wanted. But I have made it with modernizr.